# Datagrid SelectedItem lost on window.IsEnabled = false

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a (main)`Window` containing a `Frame`. A `Page` is loaded to that `Frame`, with some viewmodel as its datacontext.

The View has some datagrids, where one is bound to the viewmodel and the other is bound to the selected.item (so that you get a master-details view..)

the problem occurs when I display a popup box, and set the mainwindow IsEnabled = false. When that happens, the selected item from the datagrid bound to the viewmodel gets unselected, and of course the other datagrids selected items get unselected as well.

How can I preserve the "state" of the UI when my mainwindow.IsEnabled get set to false?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some insanity to the mix.  After installing VS 2011 Beta (which replaces the .NET 4.0 framework with .NET 4.5) I created a small test application with **VS 2010 which targets 4.0** and the behaviour of this has changed once again to not set SelectedItem = null when the grid is disabled.  I don't know if this will make it into the final version of 4.5 or not....

Comment: Oh, so that's why one machine with W7 is set to null and other don't. It looks like it's a default behavior to not set to null since Net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

It seems the builtin behaviour of the datagrid is to deselect the selected item when the datagrid gets disabled - just verified this myself.

But try this:

Create a simplistic ListView, add some data, select an item, click a button to disable the ListView. If the selected item gets deselected, then this behaviour is by design in WPF. Not much you can do about it I think. Other than not disabling your controls...

If the selected item does not get deselected you can open a bug in Connect. It might take months to get a reply and a fix "might" come in a couple of years... If such a wait is not an option the also post a bug in the WPF toolkit (wpf.codeplex.com). The toolkit might get updated sooner.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, and by design, but it is both unexpected and annoying and a lot of people think it should be removed. The workaround it to create a new `DataGrid` class that inherits from `DataGrid` that changed the behaviour of this event.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Class="MyDataGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  public MyDataGrid()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  static MyDataGrid()
  {
    IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(MyDataGrid), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnIsEnabledChanged));
  }

  private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(
    DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    d.CoerceValue(CanUserAddRowsProperty);
    d.CoerceValue(CanUserDeleteRowsProperty);

    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
  }
}
```

See http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/13022